# Auth0 react native gives invalid tokens

Tags: django, react-native, auth0

I am developing an application with a React Native application and a Django Rest Framework backend. Now, when users are authenticated in React Native, and I use the `getCredentials()` function from the `useAuth0()` hook, I get an `accessToken` and an `idToken`. However, both of these tokens are unable to authenticate in the Django REST framework application, returning the following:

```json
{
    "detail": "Invalid token."
}
```

I followed [this](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/django/01-authorization) tutorial to integrate Auth0 with django.

Maybe this has something to do with the fact that the Django api is registered as an API in Auth0 and that it has an identifier? Because this identifier is nowhere mentioned in the React native client.

Any help/insights are appreciated.

Comment: How have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track - Your access token (which is the only token to be validated by your backend) needs to have an `aud` claim which should contain the API identifier you set in Auth0. See the docs on [validating access tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/access-tokens/validate-access-tokens).